# Как можно загрузить несколько изображений в opencv?

Tags: opencv, изображения

Помогите, пожалуйста. У меня есть программа, где можно загрузить несколько цветных изображений одновременно. Но мне нужно одновременно загрузить черно-белые изображения.

```
     #include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
     #include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
     #include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

      using namespace std;
      using namespace cv;

    int main(){
    cv::Mat frame,frame32f;
    char filename[40];
    cv::Mat mean;
    const int count =10;
    const int width  = 1920;
    const int height = 1080;
    cv::Mat resultframe = cv::Mat::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
    for(int i = 1 ; i<= count; i++){
    sprintf(filename,"d:\\BMdvideos\\images\\image%d.tiff",i);
    frame = imread(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    frame.convertTo(frame32f,CV_32FC3);
    resultframe +=frame32f;
        cout << " i = " << i<<endl;
    //frame.release();
    }
    resultframe *= (1.0/count);

    imshow("",resultframe);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cv::Mat images[IMAGES_COUNT];
for(int i = 0; i < IMAGES_COUNT; i++)
{
    images[i] = imread(filename[i], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
}
```

Загружено несколько изображений. Второй параметр функции imread, указывает какое изображение мы читаем.

Я правильно ваш вопрос понял?